# Struts2 : Problem in redirecting From other site to myApplication

Tags: tomcat, struts2

I am using struts2.0 and the application is deployed and tested over tomcat 6.0.

As per requirement, my application (**myApplication**) has to redirect from a PHP site with domain name **http:// abc.com**

When this PHP site redirects the request to my application it calls an action **Action1** of my application, which further **redirects** to another action **Action2**. But while redirection it changes the domain name to Application's server IP (**http://applicationServerIP:8080/myApplication/Action2** ).  My expected result is 
( **http://abc.com/myApplication/Action2**).

**Action configuration in sturts.xml is:**

```
<action name="Action1" class="Action1">
    <result name="success" type="redirectAction">Action2</result>
</action>

<action name="Action2" class="Action2">
    <result name="success">/myJSP.jsp</result>
</action>
```

**Any Help to solve this issue will be appreciated.**

Answer (score 0):

By placing the following tag in /myJSP.jsp

```
<s:a>here</s:a> //I will write the current url as struts understands it.
```

Will show that struts will take the incoming url as the gospel in determining what the server name is.

So your application is being called with http://applicationServerIP:8080/myApplication/Action2 just change the call to http://abc.com/myApplication/Action2

If this is not what you want you'll need to change the URL before it reaches struts2. Some containers have built in support for this or an add-on/plug-in (I just use iptables).

Answer (score 0):

You must bypass struts-config, because this only redirect to your own application, Try this:

```
public ActionForward method(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
                HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){
       response.sendRedirect("http://www.example.com");
       return null;
}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome on StackOverflow. Thanks for you answer, but some more explanation would help further the original poster. Please try to add a bit more details on why the code you provide solves the issue